# Windows program to lower bitrate of M4A files without re-encoding

Tags: windows, windows-7, audio, music, audio-editing

**Background:**

I have a music playlist of `.M4A` files (AAC codecs) at varying bitrates that I'd like to lower to a set bitrate for the purpose of conserving space on the phone that I'll be transferring them to. Because many of these files were downloaded directly from YouTube (using `youtube-dl`), I'd like to avoid re-encoding them.

**Therefore, I'm looking for a Windows program that...**

- Works on Windows 7
- Is free
- Is a **GUI program**, not a command-line solution
- Is able to convert a **batch of `.M4A` files** to a **set** bitrate **without re-encoding**

Thanks, would really appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: By definition if you change the bitrate you will have to re-encode - otherwise you will get nonsense - it is a bit like saying that you wish to change then number of pages in a book without re-laying out the text.

Comment: So it can't be done? Are you positive on that? I could have sworn I've heard references to lossless re-encoding during my extensive reading up on the topic, especially when it concerns the same file format. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Lossless re-encoding is __not__ the same as __without__ re-encoding which is what your question is asking! So yes I am 100% sure that what you are currently asking cannot be done.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify; when I said lossless re-encoding, I meant re-encoding lossy files without further loss, rather than re-encoding lossless file formats.

Comment: The problem is that your __question__ says _"without re-encoding"_ not "re-encoding without further loss" - Anyway a lower bit rate will almost always result in further losses as there is less data bandwidth available in a lower bit rate - that is what it means.

Comment: @SteveBarnes - I understand where you're coming from. If you'd like to make that an answer I'll award you the bounty and I'll post a new question rephrasing the question properly - unless you're also sure that "re-encoding without further loss" can't be done either?

Comment: Answer added to attempt to help anybody looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly the question as asked cannot be done as changing the bit rate **must** always require re-encoding and reducing the bit rate will *almost always* reduce the quality of the track - the exceptions will be when the track had already been processed to increase the bit rate above that which was originally recorded *but not always in this case* or for simple waveforms that fit the new bit rate as well as they do the old.

Think of it as changing the size of the pages in a book, unless you reflow or scale the text and images you cannot do it and retain all of the original information *unless you are lucky enough that all of the page contents fit within the new page dimensions without change because there happened to be large borders*.

There are a number of GUI based Audio Editors that can change the bit rate on save or export and support `.M4A` format, necessarily re-encoding the format but not many that I know of that support batch processing.

- [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) allows you to create a 'Chain' of operations which can include exporting with given settings and apply them to the opened file but opens a window for each file so still requires a fair amount of manual intervention.
- [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) may well be able to do this but it certainly isn't clear how.

This brings us back to a not GUI option [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) which can do this with ease and with minimal loss of quality. This can easily be input into a batch file containing something like:

```
REM UNTESTED!
for fn in $* (
   ffmpeg -i %fn% -c:a aac -b:a 160k fixedrate/%fn%
)
```

That you coud then drop your files onto.

There are a number of FFMPEG GUIs such as [AVAINTI](http://www.avanti.arrozcru.org) & [FfmpegYAG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpegyag/) that are worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. With regards to the ffmpeg syntax - don't percent signs have to be doubled up for batch files?

Comment: @Hashim as I said untested

Answer (score 1):

Hashim,
Have you looked into what VLC can do: https://www.vlchelp.com/convert-audio-format/ ?